# Using NSString as Hyperlink

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, nsstring

I have a Master and a Detail view Controller. My Master view Controller is a tableView Controller. In my Detail view Controller i have a Button and a NSString called urlString

Example: When the user taps cell 1, the value of urlString is set to google.com If the User taps Cell 2, the value of urlString is set to Apple.com

Now i want that of you tap the Button in the Detail view Controller, it open up Safari and opens the url set in urlString

Comment: sorry for asking... but what is your question exactly? you description looks a massive chaos to me. I have no clue about what you'd like to achieve here. where is you button? what is the connection between the button and the table cells? where the string with the link comes from?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the text of button -

```
[yourButton setTitle:@"your String" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: NO, i want to let the Button Open a web Site in Safari. And the link for this should be my so called urlString

Comment: not clear what you are asking, from native app you want to open safari and button needs to look like a urlString???

Comment: Ok. I have a Master and a Detail view Controller. My Master view Controller is à tableView Controller.  In my Detail view Controller i have a Button and a NSString called urlString  Example: Whe the user taps cell 1, the value of urlString is set to http://google.com  If the User taps Cell 2, the value of urlString is set to http://Apple.com  Now i want that of you tap the Button in the Detail view Controller, it open up Safari and opens the url set in urlString  Have you understood what i mean?

Comment: @user3786233, maybe you have adding those details to your OP not as a comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Step1, set the title of your button

```
    [_myButton setTitle:@"my_url" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Step2, when you press the button, open the link

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
    {
        NSString * url = [@"http://" stringByAppendingString:sender.titleLabel.text];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURLString]];
```

Comment: Ok, I solved it!

    - (IBAction)urlButton:(id)sender {
        
        NSString * url = urlString;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    }